# Visual Studio 2017 - Installation issue, No option to uninstall

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10

While upgrading Visual studio 2017 v15.4 the installation hanged up for hours and later I have forcibly restarted the machine. I know many of you might have gone through the same, appreciate your time for replying to this issue.

Thereafter tried opening the VS shell, it prompted me "*The setup of this installation of Visual studio is not complete. Please run the Visaul studio Installer again to correct the issue.*" (shown as below)
[image]

As a last resort looked at the uninstall option but Vs installer is not prompting me with such option

[image: Installer is showing only an option to Install]
Alternatively tried installing from VS_enterprise.exe and installation directory marked as incomplete as shown below
[image]

Comment: You uninstall it the way you uninstall any program.  Control Panel > Programs and Features.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I did the same way and am seeing a message that it is not allowing me to install default program file path (as I highlighted in red).

Comment: It seems the uninstall did not completely remove everything.  Maybe you installed other stuff, like VS extensions.  Use Explorer to have a look at what remained behind.